# Separate SSHD Authpriv logs into /var/log/sshd, all other authpriv logging goes to messages

Tags: linux, logs, syslog, sshd

Right now, sshd is using the `authpriv` facility.  The level of logging is fine, but I don't want it in the syslog, I want it to go to `/var/log/sshd` (which doesn't yet exist) on Red Hat Linux/Enterprise Linux. `authpriv` is configured to go to syslog by `syslogd.conf`.  Do I need to change the facility on sshd to `local2` (or any other unused local) for instance, and then direct `local2` to `/var/log/sshd` or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Using ryslog you can set up a filter to redirect the log messages:

```
if $syslogfacility-text == 'authpriv' and $programname == 'sshd' then
    action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/sshd")
if $programname == 'sshd' then ~
```